# How to do a live table search using jquery with pagination?

Tags: jquery

I have a large table with many pages,I found some code can do a live table search,but it only valid on page already showed. how can i make it valid on all data?

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $(".search").keyup(function () {
    var searchTerm = $(".search").val();
    var listItem = $('.results tbody').children('tr');
    var searchSplit = searchTerm.replace(/ /g, "'):containsi('")

  $.extend($.expr[':'], {'containsi': function(elem, i, match, array){
        return (elem.textContent || elem.innerText || '').toLowerCase().indexOf((match[3] || "").toLowerCase()) >= 0;
    }
  });

  $(".results tbody tr").not(":containsi('" + searchSplit + "')").each(function(e){
    $(this).attr('visible','false');
  });

  $(".results tbody tr:containsi('" + searchSplit + "')").each(function(e){
    $(this).attr('visible','true');
  });

  var jobCount = $('.results tbody tr[visible="true"]').length;
    $('.counter').text(jobCount + ' item');

  if(jobCount == '0') {$('.no-result').show();}
    else {$('.no-result').hide();}
          });
});
```

thanks

Comment: Hmm. I'm thinking, what if on keypress event on thje search box remove the pagination and load all the data, in that way you can live search all thru out the data. Hope that made sense

Answer (score 0):

As per your search code, it is not possible to search for the data which is not inserted into the table, what you can do is you can insert all the data in a table on the first load.

**For example:** let's say you have `67` records with page size `10`, now there would be `7` pages. Now you can insert 67 `<tr>` into the table on page load, and only show first 10 `<tr>` on the first page and hide other 57 `<tr>`. On page 2 you can show 11 - 20 rows and hide other rows. Similarly with other pages, Now when you'll run your js code you'll get the desired result.

However, loading all data on the first load in the table will increase the page load time and also it's not a good approach to follow.